# HTTP forwarding PLAINTEXT warning

Tags: php, apache, ssl, mod-rewrite, redirect

When I run this SSL test:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=rickschmitz.network

I get the following warning :

> HTTP forwarding http://www.rickschmitz.network   PLAINTEXT

What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that when requesting in HTTPS the response is a redirection to an HTTP URL (http://www.rickschmitz.network as given by SSLLabs). The browser is supposed to warn you when you are leaving the "secure" browsing. To fix it, check your Apache configuration at the SSL virtual host (should be in `conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf`)

Comment: I can't find that folder, have no conf/extra in apache.
only can find in etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf but thats disabled.
I just searched the whole server, there is no httpd-ssl on it

Comment: Your installation might be different from the default Apache, but in all case you have a redirection HTTPS -> HTTP somewhere.

Comment: i use a redirect in the vhost itself:
<VirtualHost 5.157.82.219:80>  
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =rickschmitz.network [OR]
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.rickschmitz.network
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

Comment: this RewriteRule redirects HTTP -> HTTPS. You are looking for the contrary. I can't help more, you need to check all the config files and if you aren't sure of what files you have exactly, run 'httpd -S'

Comment: does htaccess count if it is redirecting links to http? (not directly https to http but just anything to http?

Comment: i found a file /etc/apache2/conf.d/httpd.conf
My server is Ubuntu 18.04 Apache2 with php7 FPM

Comment: Yes, all config files count (including htaccess). The command 'locate httpd' should find it.

Comment: thank you then i think i solved the problem, if i re-check the warning is gone now. i changed the redirects in htaccess.
The only httpd i find is /etc/apache2/conf.d/httpd.conf  what i manualy created..

one more question, i now have 2 'same' vhosts the one for port 80 and the one for port 443 (https) but if i disable the old port 80 vhost config it does not work anymore. is it normal that i need the vhost config for port 80 still?

Comment: No. You can go in production with the SSL virtual host only. But to be sweet with people who forget to type _https://_ when starting browsing on your site, we usually let this virtual host on port 80 live, with a minimal configuration for redirecting http -> https.