# HTTP forwarding Plaintext warning (nginx)

Tags: http, nginx, redirect, https

So I was updating my nginx configuration to meet some security checks, to get grade A+ from Qualys SSL Labs.

I do get A+, but one of the warnings I don't understand. I get this:

[image]

Though, I do have http redirect to https and it seems its working fine. **Does anyone know what would be the cause of this warning**?

I found this question: [HTTP forwarding PLAINTEXT warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50735738/http-forwarding-plaintext-warning/50737234) but it talks about apache.

I also found this: https://github.com/ssllabs/ssllabs-scan/issues/154 so it was mentioned that it could be just a bug, but now its not clear (that issue is old).

My nginx configuration:

```
http {
    upstream odoo-upstream {
        server odoo:8069 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
    }

    upstream odoo-im-upstream {
        server odoo:8072 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
    }

    # Basic Settings

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    # Enable SSL session caching for improved performance
    # http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache
    ssl_session_cache shared:ssl_session_cache:5m;
    ssl_session_timeout 24h; # time which sessions can be re-used.
    # Because the proper rotation of session ticket encryption key is
    # not yet implemented in Nginx, we should turn this off for now.
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    # Default size is 16k, reducing it can slightly improve performance.
    ssl_buffer_size 8k;
    # Gzip Settings

    gzip on;

    # http redirects to https
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    charset utf-8;

    server {
        # server port and name
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options sameorigin;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block";
        # Specifies the maximum accepted body size of a client request,
        # as indicated by the request header Content-Length.
        client_max_body_size 200m;

        # add ssl specific settings
        keepalive_timeout 60;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/domain.bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/domain.key;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

        # increase proxy buffer to handle some Odoo web requests
        proxy_buffers 16 64k;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;

        #general proxy settings
        # force timeouts if the backend dies
        proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
        proxy_send_timeout 600s;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;

        # set headers
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        # Let the Odoo web service know that we’re using HTTPS, otherwise
        # it will generate URL using http:// and not https://
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # by default, do not forward anything
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://odoo-upstream;
        }

        location /longpolling {
            proxy_pass http://odoo-im-upstream;
        }

        # cache some static data in memory for 60mins.
        # under heavy load this should relieve stress on the Odoo web interface a bit.
        location /web/static/ {
            proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
            proxy_buffering on;
            expires 864000;
            proxy_pass http://odoo-upstream;
        }
        include /etc/nginx/custom_error_page.conf;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
```